# Browser Caching of javascripts and css files in mvc project

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser-cache, single-page-application

I have to cache the static javscript and css files in my SPA(durandal+knockout) .
When i put debug='false' in my webconfig of the app , the app gives the 'jQuery not defined' and 'KO not defined' error . This is happening even when the bundles are having the jQuery and KO javascript libraries.

Any suggestions and solutions for this issue ??

Comment: I wonder, what does mvc have to do with browser caching?

Comment: are you referring towards `bundling`?

Comment: Yes..the bundle includes the javascript libraries files yet it gives these errors.

Answer (score 0):

What is the importance of specifically mentioning caching of static JavaScript and CSS and the debug='false'; You felt it was important enough to mention first but then didn't tell us what's so special about it and why we need to consider it. - We need more infomation if this is critical to the problem.

i.e.
What is special about the caching is it located somewhere other than you site?
Does you app do something different when in debug mode?
Why does debug='false' effect the bundles which are dependent ONLY on the URL you request?

#### My Guess

Does you app make different requests when in debug mode so that it can see the individual debug versions of the libraries rather than one large single line file?

Have the two libraries been included in the non debug version. I've often seen MVC projects use a partial view to load both the CSS and JavaScript

something like _Script.cshtml

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
{

 ...  All the debug ./ developer versions of files listed here individually

}
else
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
}
```

Also if your static content is 'cached' on a separate URL / Site / CDN and you used NuGet to install Knockout or other libraries then it entirely possible that the where installed in the be local /Scripts folder and not the other site.